# How to get midpoint value in OpenGLES in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es

I am new to game development. Currently I am working in simple game application, using GL_Line to draw a line and GL_Triangle strip to draw a (ball)image. Normally ball images are moving from left to right direction. When the user tab on a screen, then the line draw (top to bottom) inside the screen and to touch a ball image. So I tried to get the midpoint values from line and ball image, but i cannot know, how to start this?

Comment: Could you perhaps illustrate what it is you're trying to do? The question is rather unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a line that goes from (ax,ay) to (bx, by), the mid-point of the line is just ((ax + bx) / 2.0, (ay + by) / 2.0)).

Comment: I'm a little confused by what you're asking. Can you perhaps draw a picture to show what you're looking for if the above didn't help?

Comment: Fish image move from left to right, when the user tab on a screen, at the time line draw it, (the line and fish images are meeting a point as mid point).

Comment: To clarify - the user taps the screen and a line is drawn from the top of the screen to the bottom with the same x-coordinate where the user tapped? IS that right? And you want to find the midpoint of a line from the fish to that line? If so, you can simply use the fish's y-coordinate for both points, and the x coordinate of the tap and the fish for the x coordinates. So you'll have a line that goes from (tap.x, fish.y) to (fish.x, fish.y), and then find the midpoint of that.

Comment: Thank you so much friend,I need your help in future also. Thanks